# SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlexception

I am writing a program that connects to a SQL Server (`IGOR-PC` - SQL Server 10.50.4044 - instance `Igor-PC\Igor`)

The code is this:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = newSqlConnection("Server=.\\Igor;Database=Prueba");

myConnection.Open();
```

But I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> not monitored System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the .\\ from your server name. It should be the name only.

Comment: My server is this `IGOR-PC (SQL 10.50.4044 - Igor-PC\Igor)`, and I remove  `\\` and I have the same error

Comment: If your server is IGOR-PC why are you saying it's Igor in your connection string?

Comment: is igor pc your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Igor;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True");
```

Edit2:

[image]

For the Above Picture and for `TEST_DB` database the Connection String should be written as

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AJMOT-PC;User ID=sa;Password=thisismypassword;Initial Catalog=TEST_DB;Integrated Security=True");
```

If you are using the Window authentication for sql server then you don't need to declare the `User ID=sa;Password=thisismypassword` section.

Comment: Can I connect to this server with `JDBC`??